# android crash if spinner empty

Tags: android, crash, spinner

I have a spinner populated with data from the database. now if spinner is blank and send the data the app crashes and error as I NPE.
you advise me to do? disable the submit button if the spinner is empty? and as I disable the submit button?
thanks
this is the code of my spinner that is nela Helper class

```
 public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM  Categorie ";        
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of displaying an empty spinner ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

> disable the submit button if the spinner is empty?

If there is no data to send then Yes. I wouldn't suggest doing it simply to solve the `NPE`. The better question is "Why is it null and should it be?" But then you also have a `Spinner` with no data so I think you need to investigate why that is and what it should actually be.

> and as I disable the submit button?

I don't understand.

Comment: So, the first time the spinner is empty because the user must enter data that populate the spinner. then in an activity the user selects a value of the spinner button and using that value is added to a table. However, if the user tries to enter values ​​without first populated the spinner this crashes with the following error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I hope I explained.

Comment: Then yes, I would disable until there is appropriate data entered. However, it seems like there would be a better way. Is the `Spinner` in the same `Activity` as the one where the user enters the data to populate it?

Comment: the spinner is located in another activity
as inactive?
thanks
for your help

Comment: Then why go to that `Activity` if the user hasn't entered the information it needs?

Comment: you're right. then if the user clicks should enter a toast where it says "you must first enter the data in another activity" right? how do I? look your advice

Comment: When they click the `Button` to go to the `Activity` with the `Spinner` you can either have that `Button` disabled or display your `Toast` there. Don't let them proceed to the next `Activity` just to tell them they have to go to the previous

Comment: ok but how do I do this? for me the first time, there should be a check on the table that populates the spinner! how do I do it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand